# Using x-if doesn't bind the data in livewire wire:model

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a form with several input fields and some of them render conditionally using AlpineJS `x-if`, those elements have `wire:model` data, but when the elements rendered conditionally the model binding seems not working. I tried to print the variable on the element but it doesn't work. Without `x-if` it works fine.

```php
<div class="form-check" >
                <input class="form-check-input appearance-none rounded-full h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 bg-white checked:bg-[#60D619] checked:border-[#60D619] focus:outline-none transition duration-200 mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2 cursor-pointer" type="radio"  id="company" wire:model="isCompany" @click="open = true" value="true">
                <label class="form-check-label inline-block px-1 text-sm text-gray-600" for="company">
                    Yes, I'm a company.
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input appearance-none rounded-full h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 bg-white checked:bg-[#60D619] checked:border-[#60D619] focus:outline-none transition duration-200 mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2 cursor-pointer" type="radio" id="person" wire:model="isCompany" @click="open = false" value="false">
                <label class="form-check-label inline-block px-1 text-sm text-gray-600" for="person">
                    No. I'm not a company.
                </label>
            </div>

                <div class="py-1"  x-show="open" x-transition>
                    <span class="px-1 text-sm text-gray-600">Company Name</span>
                    <input wire:model.lazy="companyName" placeholder="" type="text"
                           class="text-md block px-3 py-2 rounded-lg w-full
bg-white border-2 border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-600 shadow-md focus:placeholder-gray-500 focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-600 focus:outline-none">
                </div>

            <div class="py-1" x-show="!open" x-transition>
                <span class="px-1 text-sm text-gray-600">User Name</span>
                <input wire:model="name" placeholder="" type="text"
                       class="text-md block px-3 py-2 rounded-lg w-full
bg-white border-2 border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-600 shadow-md focus:placeholder-gray-500 focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-600 focus:outline-none">
            </div>

            <div class="py-1" x-show="!open" x-transition>
                <span class="px-1 text-sm text-gray-600">First Name</span>
                <input wire:model="fullName" placeholder="" type="text"
                       class="text-md block px-3 py-2 rounded-lg w-full
bg-white border-2 border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-600 shadow-md focus:placeholder-gray-500 focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-600 focus:outline-none">
            </div>
```

When `x-show` uses the issue goes away but the unnecessary input fields are not cleared. I don't want those data to be saved on the database. Is this because `x-show` only toggles the visibility of the elements and `x-if` completely removes the element from the DOM? Or is there a way to reset the values of the input fields when visibility is toggled using `x-show`?

Comment: You could define a function in `x-data` to both toggle visibility *and* clear those fields on `@click`

Answer (score 2):

`x-if` indeed removes the element, while `x-show` only hides it.

`wire:model` only works if it's loaded in with Livewire. Else Livewire doesn't "know" those fields exist, and thus can't add an event listener to detect change/input/etc. Therefore, you want to do what @Bennett already mentioned, and only hide the inputs, and clear the fields.

You can use [$wire](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#interacting-with-livewire-from-alpine) to directly clear the input. Otherwise, you will have to dispatch a change or input [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) on the input field (change for lazy, input for non-lazy).